# Preprocess function is not working with extension setting in view data export module

Tags: views

I have Installed the view data export module and enabled the extension setting "Provide as file" in view. It is working properly but I need to format the csv file so I have used "hook_preprocess_views_data_export_csv_body(&$vars)".

The issue is that when I enabling extension setting, preprocess code is not working.